# Export list of users with first and lastname in WP-CLI

Tags: wp-cli

I want to export a CSV file with a list of my Wordpress site users with WP-CLI. I can do this but I'm getting my users first and lastname together in one column (display name), I would like to get them each in their own column. Is there a way to do this? I can't find first and lastname as available options in the docs that lists optional fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation for [`wp user list`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/user/list/), the `fields` argument accepts any valid `WP_User_Query` field.

Thus, you can simply use `wp user list --fields=first_name,last_name --format=csv` to list all users with their first and last names. Of course you can add any other fields that you need.

Note: You can get the documentation for each command using the `--help` flag, where things like that are mentioned.